# Would this be considered too broad/open ended?

Tags: discussion

If  i were to ask a question for the best programming language for a specific task but gave specific factors that would be taken into account would it still be too broad/flame/opinion.

---

For example if i asked

> What are the best/required languages for creating a windows driver with a GUI frontend that would also be run as service in terms of:
>
> Speed of execution
> Production time
> Flexibility
> Maintainability
> Compatibility of languages involved/ease of integration.

Would that be acceptable or instantly closed ?

Comment: I've never written a driver, but this sounds like it would be more of an *architectural* problem than a language selection problem.  Also, you'd have to expand why a driver needs a GUI and a Service.

Comment: @MetaFight Yeah i would definitely expand the question in terms of why and how i want to implement this.I was just asking this as sort of a basis of the question to see if it would be alright,instead of putting loads of effort into it and it just being closed.

Answer (score 4):

This would be instantly closed. Please see the Meta question [Why was my question closed or down voted?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6483/), especially the points [Off Topic: What technology to take up next](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6486/) and [Off Topic: Recommend a tool, library, or other](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6487/).

While your metrics try to make the question objective, such recommendation questions are still ill-suited for Programmers.SE. Also, your metrics fail to provide an objective framework since nearly each metric is highly subjective, and the relation of metrics to each other is not defined – if a language ranks high on speed and low on productivity, is this better than a language that ranks medium on both axes?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply. Is there anyway i could make it objective or word it in a way where i could get an answer/not have it closed? Or somewhere you could recommend to ask such a question ?

Comment: @User112638726 You could try asking open-ended questions like this on [http://www.reddit.com/r/programmerchat](http://www.reddit.com/r/programmerchat) instead

Answer (score 2):

As amon just mentioned your question as-is would probably get closed.

However, I think there might be something interesting buried in there.

If you shifted the focus of the question away from technology & metrics, and focused on the requirements you're trying to fulfil (have a GUI, provide functionality as a service, provide a device driver) you could have a really interesting *architectural* question.

Comment: Okay, I'll see if i can work out a way to flesh out a good architctural question :) Also do you know anywhere where i could get advice on what language would be suitable for this task ?